# How to get a Spring Batch Job to run on startup and not as Scheduled

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application that is working fine, but configured as Scheduled, how can i have it run once at startup and end execution once finished ?

Here is the configuration:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 500000)
public void runJob() {
    try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong(
                "time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(processJob, jobParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Bean
public Job processJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("processJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener())
            .flow(orderStep1()).end().build();
}
```

And the Application main Class:

```
   @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= "com.companyName")
   @EnableBatchProcessing
   @EnableScheduling
   public class ExpansionDBApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       SpringApplication.run(ExpansionDBApplication.class, args);
    }
   }
```

Edit:
After removeing the annotations @Scheduled and @EnableScheduling the Job doesn't start and 2 warnings apper:

```
2019-01-03 09:20:54.438  WARN 14476 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2019-01-03 09:20:54.444  WARN 14476 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
```

They refer to these fields:

```
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private Job processJob;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Spring Batch application that is working fine, but configured as Scheduled, how can i have it run once at startup and end execution once finished ?

Well, just remove the scheduling configuration (`@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 500000)`) and it will run at startup and end once finished.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, i made the changes and edit the question with the results.

Comment: The warnings were fixed in v3.0.9 and 4.0.1 (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2161), so they should disappear if you upgrade to one of these versions. However, I can't know why the job does not start anymore. How do you run your app?

Comment: I can run it using the IDE (InteliJ) or by command line java -jar [jarName]

Comment: Normally, if you use the `spring-boot-batch-starter` and you define a bean of type `Job` in your context, Spring Boot will run the job at JVM startup, unless you add `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` to your application properties. Do you have this property? Probably you added this when using scheduling was configured for your app?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i did had "spring.batch.job.enabled" configured to false, once i changed it to true and remove the Scheduled annotation - it runs at startup and end execution once complete - thanks again !

Answer (score 4):

You could also override run method and control job execution via program arguments.

This can be useful when you have configured more than one job.

```js
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.companyName")
@EnableBatchProcessing
class ExpansionDBApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
  @Autowired
  private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
  @Autowired
  private ListableJobLocator listableJobLocator;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ExpansionDBApplication.class);
    app.run(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws JobExecutionException {
    SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
    String jobName = source.getProperty("job.name");
    if (jobName == null || jobName.isEmpty()) {
      executeAllJobs();
    } else {
      executeJob(jobName);
    }
  }

  private void executeJob(String jobName) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("uid", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .toJobParameters();
    jobLauncher.run(listableJobLocator.getJob(jobName), jobParameters);
  }

  private void executeAllJobs() throws JobExecutionException {
    for (String jobName : listableJobLocator.getJobNames()) {
      executeJob(jobName);
    }
  }
}
```